# Xmonad paste special character \x00f6 with pasteString?

Tags: haskell, unicode, utf-8, ghc, xmonad

When using Xmonad.Util.Paste I'm trying to paste a `ö` character with `pasteString` but nothing appears. How can I paste this character?

I tried to use:

```
 , ((mod4Mask                , xK_o      ),   pasteString "ö")
```

But this gave me a compilation error (which I expected): `lexical error in string/character literal (UTF-8 decoding error)` So I looked up the corresponding escape sequence [here](http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/) and tried the following line:

```
 , ((mod4Mask                , xK_o      ),   pasteString "\x00f6")
```

This compiled fine but when pressing the key combination nothing seems to appear (I tried it with a regular string and it worked fine, also pasteSelection works like intended). What am I doing wrong?

On a side note: I also tried `\x00F6` but it didn't make any difference. Also I'm using `ghc version 7.8.4`.

#### Update 1:

I found [this](http://cheatsheet.codeslower.com/CheatSheet.pdf) cheatsheet for haskell, so I tried the string `\xC\&4` which results in `,4`. When only using `\&4` it results in `4` and when using `\x2C` it prints `,`.

#### Update 2:

It seems like XMonad.Util.Paste doesn't work with Umlauts at all, as mentioned the function pasteSelection works. But when selecting an `ö` character it doesn't. So I guess I need to use `xdotool` or something similar.

Your help would be appreciated a lot, thanks for looking at this issue!

Comment: Can you try `\xC3\xB6`?

Comment: @nj_ Thanks for your help, but it didn't work. The result is the same as with `\x00f6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pasteString` maps `pasteChar` over each char in the string; `pasteChar`, in turn, have trouble with non-ASCII characters, which is stated in the comments to [the source code](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/src/XMonad-Util-Paste.html#pasteString):

> Note that this function makes use of 'stringToKeysym', and so will probably have trouble with any 'Char' outside ASCII.

In light of that, I suggest setting up an X Compose key, where you can type "ö" with <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>.